# AS3 - Add one visual element into another?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm new to Flash and AS3.

I'm trying to make a word Scrabble game. I'm stuck for the code to :

- Show object (the word) in the blank box,
- Validate the clicked answer is true same as the picture or not.

Thank you before, sorry for the bad english.

[image]

Comment: Unclear what or where the **problem** or **error** is **within your code** so we cannot help you fix anything. To get started, using a search engine look for tutorials about : **AS3 instance name** for object access, look into **AS3 addChild** to add (by instance name) into another object (it also has own instance name). Look into **AS3 If Else statements** then apply the logic for any validating / checking... You might also want to learn about **AS3 Boolean** for true/false checks.. Also learn about **AS3 Mouse Events**.

Comment: Thank you VC One for the help

Answer (score 0):

To add one visual element into another, first you have to make sure the container is an instance of DisplayObjectContainer (that is, Stage, a Sprite or a MovieClip).
Then, you can use:

```
// Add on top of everything else
container.addChild(content);
// Add on the bottom of everything else
container.addChildAt(content, 0);
```